# CSS - Stacked borders

Tags: html, css, border, overlap

I have this layout that needs to be a bunch of boxes stacked on top of each other, they all have a 1px border.
In order to have the border always be 1px I put a margin-bottom of -1px to all of the boxes, but when I change the border color on hover it doesn't quite work as intended. Here's an example:
[image: Border collapsed]

How can I make it so it doesn't overlap on hover?

My code:

```
.main-content ul li a {
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  padding:15px 23px;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #545353;
  color:#545353;
}
.main-content ul li a:hover {
  border-color:#fff;
  color:#fff;
}
```

I tried giving them all a z-index and then making that higher on hover, but it didn't work either... 
Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT** Adding HTML

```
<div class="row main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Bienvenida</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">¿Por qué es la decisión correcta?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">¿Cómo funciona este servicio?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">¿Cuánto cuesta este servicio?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estoy interesado, ¿qué hago?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using `position:absolute;` and `z-index` on `:hover` does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

so that elements are exactly the width and height you want them to be. The border will be 1px within the element instead of stretching out to other ones.
ewfaeg
To keep the border at 1px, use this css:

```
.main-content ul li a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 30;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    padding:15px 23px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #545353;
    color:#545353;
}
.main-content ul li a:hover {
    border-color:#fff;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

The changes I made was setting a z-index for both unhovered links and hovered links. The position:relative is added because z-index does not reflect unless there is a position specified.

Comment: That works, but when the boxes meet there's 2px becase both borders meet, what I want is for the borders to stack on top of each other, but when I hover on an item that elements border should be the one "on top"

Comment: You can try using z-index instead and apply them to the box on hover. What z-index does is prioritize one element on the screen over another, which seems to be what you want. You can do this by:
.main-content ul li a:hover {
z-index:10;
}
while the rest are of z-index less than that. You also need to set position to absolute or relative for this to work.

Comment: I tried putting z-index:99; on a:hover but that didn't work either, is there anything I'm missing here? How could I make it work with pos. absolute?

Comment: there, sorry for the delay!

Comment: Worked! Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/L565nwaL/1/

```
<div class="main-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item three large</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-content ul li a {
  padding:15px 23px;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #545353;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  color:#545353;
}
.main-content ul li a:hover {
  border:1px solid #fff;
  color:#fff;

} 

.main-content {
    background: #161616;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Comment: That works, but again, there's two pixels where the boxes meet where there should only be one

Comment: I thought about that, but since some boxes are larger than others you can see there being no bottom border

Comment: Yea i figured that out after i posted answer :) Sorry about that.